# Model for SelectList in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a POC app using MVC. Models are Employees, Departments, Locations, Vendors. Multiple Razor pages will need select lists for Employees. I know that I could create a model for Employees in each page folder. Could I instead create a model for Employees in the Models folder and use that for multiple pages? If so, how would I address that model in each page?
According to the tutorials, the syntax within the cshtml page is

```
    <select asp-for="Course.DepartmentID" class="form-control"
                    asp-items="@Model.DepartmentNameSL">
                <option value="">-- Select Department --</option>
```

which addresses the model within the page folder.
How would I code it to address the model in the models folder?

Should have included more code.:(

I have an Employee model and a Department model. The Department model has a field for the DepartmentManager which should contain the EmployeeID from the Employee model for the employee assigned as manager to that department.

```
    Employee Model................................
    public Guid EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    Department Model..............................
    public Guid DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentCode { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public Guid? DepartmentManager { get; set; }<-----This is EmployeeID in Employee Model
```

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

If your multiple pages need this drop-down list, you can create a general method to get it, and then pass it to the view through `ViewData`.

```
public SelectList GetSelect(ApplicationDbContext _context)
{
    return (SelectList)(ViewData["DepartmentNameSL"] = new SelectList(_context.Department.ToList(), "DepartmentID", "DepartmentName"));
}
```

Then in your action,you can use it:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    GetSelect(_context);
    return View();
}
```

In your View:

```
<select name="Course_DepartmentID" asp-items="ViewBag.DepartmentNameSL">
</select>
```